# Powershell Issue with setting inheritance

Tags: powershell-2.0, file-permissions

I have a script that I need some assistance in configuring permission inheritance on a collection of folders and subfolders

Here's what I have so far:

```
    cls
    Set-Location "C:\Set-ACL"
    $log = "C:\Set-ACL\Folders.txt"
    #Gets the ACL's from a folder with correct permissions set
    $ACL = Get-Acl -Path "C:\Folder\subfolder\subfolder\subfolder"
   '$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Folder\Subfolder\*\*" | Select-String -pattern "01-"'
    $Folders >> $log

    Start-Process $log -Wait
    #Function to pause script while ignoring certain keys like Ctrl etc.
    'Function Pause4user($M = "Press any key to continue setting ACL's Ctrl + C to quit  . . . ") { If ($psISE) { $S = New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"; $B = $S.Popup("Click OK to continue.", 0, "Script Paused", 0); Return }; Write-Host -NoNewline $M; $I = 16, 17, 18, 20, 91, 92, 93, 144, 145, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183; While ($K.VirtualKeyCode -Eq $Null -Or $I -Contains $K.VirtualKeyCode) { $K = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown") }; Write-Host }'
    Pause4user

    foreach ($Folder in $Folders)
    {

Set-ACL -Path $Folders -AclObject $ACL
Write-Host "ACL's Set"
Remove-Item $log

    }
```

The issue i'm finding is that the permissions I have defined in the variable $ACL are not passed to all subfolders and using -recurse after the Get-ChildItem looks like it would do the job but doesnt work because of the 260 character limit in the path.

Is there a way to set the permissions on the folders returned in the $Folders variable and inherit these permissions to everything underneath it therefore not running into the path limit?

P.S. Go easy on the script it was put together quickly!

Thanks in advance

Comment: you declare a $folder variable, but you never use it

Answer (score 0):

Yeah as @Cole9350 said. In your for loop is it mean to be $Folder? at the moment $Folders points to the collection and not the item in the collection

Also, when you declare $Folders you don't need the single quotes surrounding the statement

Comment: I was trying to say something like for each individual folder returned by the $Folders variable then run Set-ACL on it. I guess my for each statement is wrong. But ideally I'd like for there to be a way of setting the permissions on $Folders to be the same as the permissions defined in $ACL -this happens on that level but doesnt inherit down to the files and folders in all subfolders and files below.